# Many to many relationships EF Core 5.0.3

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to replicate discords users model for my own site and the rules are.

A User can be part of multiple clubs
Each user within those clubs can have the roles of admin or mod.

So Far I have site wide roles working but not within the club entity and I am having trouble linking up my clubs to the users

This is what I have so far I am using ef core 5.0.3 if that makes a difference.

ApplicaitonUser Model

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public enum UserTypeEnum
    {
        Guest=0,
        User=1,
        Author=2,
        AddonOwner=3,
        GroupOwner=5,
        ClubMember=6,
        ClubAdmin=7,
        SuperAdmin=199,
        BandUser=999
    }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? GamerTag { get; set; }
    public bool? isOnline { get; set; }
    public int? UserType { get; set; }
    public Guid? TennantId { get; set; }
    public Guid? ClubId { get; set; }

    public List<Badges>? Badges { get; set; }

    public List<Club>? Clubs { get; set; }

}
```

Then In my clubs I have

```
public  class Club
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? TeannatId { get; set; }
    public Guid? ClubId { get; set; }
    public Guid? UserId { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }       
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public string? Url { get; set; }
    public int? ClubLikes { get; set; }
    public int? ClubDislikes { get; set; }
    public int? MembersCount { get; set; }
    public string? Logo { get; set; }
    public List<Flight>? Flights { get; set; }
    public string? ThumbNail { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? GpdrRemoveRequestDate { get; set; }
    public bool? isGpdrRemoveRequest { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? BannedTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan? BanPeriod { get; set; }
    public bool? isBanned { get; set; }
    public bool? isActive { get; set; }
    public bool? isDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string? CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public  List<ApplicationUser>? Members { get; set; }
}
```

I tried this so far

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Club>().Property(x => x.ClubId).HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "Admin".ToUpper() });
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .HasOne<Club>()
            .WithMany(m => m.Members)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.ClubId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(c => c.ClubId);
    }
```

But it only gives me a admin user and not roles within clubs also. The mapping for club only allows for one club per members when they could be part of multiple clubs its the exact same principle for discord where a channel would be a club and a user could be a mod or a normal user.

Then in my view I am returning.

```
 var club = await _context.Clubs.Include(c =>c.Members).ToListAsync();
 return View(club);
```

Where I would expect to see the many members per club but each member in term could belong to a different club multple times

**Edit 2 still issues**

I am still getting a zero count on my club users from the below person answer is their something else i must configure

[image]

Comment: you dont need to do string?.  a string is already nullable.  Just food for thought.

Comment: @ChampChris maybe he/she has nullable enabled. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references . If he/she doesn't then you are right.

Comment: @BenceL thanks for that.  I wasn't aware of that in c# 8.

Comment: @BenceL sometimes you cant avoid nulls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a table for an association between club and user to allow a user belong to multiple clubs. It is under that table you define the role of the user for that particular club.

```
public class ClubMember
{ 
    public string UserId {get;set;} 
    public int ClubId {get; set;} 
    public ApplicationUser User {get; set;} 
    public Club Club {get; set;} 
    public string RoleId {get;set;} 
    public IdentityRole Role {get; set;} 
}
```

Remove `List<Club> Clubs {get; set;}` from ApplicationUser and also remove `List<ApplicationUser> Members {get;set;}` from `Club`

Then you can add the following properties to `ApplicationUser` and `Club`

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public virtual List<ClubMember> ClubMembers{get;set;} 
} 
public class Club
{
   public virtual List<ClubMember> ClubMembers{get;set;} 
}
```

**Update**

To assign a club to a user, it's important you do;

```
var clubmember = new ClubMember {UserId = userId, ClubId = clubId, RoleId = roleId};
_context.ClubMembers.Add(clubmember);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

To query all members in a club with Id = 7 for example, you could do this;

```
var membersInClub = _context.ClubMembers.Include(c => c.User).Where(c => c.ClubId == 7).Select(c => c.User);
```

To query all clubs and their members

```
var clubs = _conext.Clubs.Include(c.ClubMembers);
```

Comment: Sorry does the Second ment to be Club Mmember u call it club user i persume that a typo and do i not need anything in model creating using this method.

Comment: @rogue39nin Yes, club members. There's no need to map anything in OnModelCreating. Also, you could just rename your ApplicationUser to MemberUser for your own clarity sake, but if it's fine this way, no problem.

Comment: how would i seed the roles for the roles within the clubs just the normal way /

Comment: @rogue39nin You could just try seed it the way you'll seed users. An uneffecient way I could think of is; when you try to add a user to a club (i.e. to the ClubMember table), you can just do a check to see if the roles exist, if they don't, create them

Comment: please see edit 2 above still getting zero members even though i do have clubs assigned to those users?

Comment: Do I still need to place ClubMembers into db set for ef core and store it their ?

Comment: @rogue39nin Yes, ClubMembers is also a table. Can you also update how you are assigning the clubs to users?

Comment: It will be buy an invite which will have the club Id in the body of the link and the user id as guids

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228627/discussion-between-qudus-and-rogue39nin).

Comment: I will try your link examples first mate.